# How fast do large asteroids usually travel?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, space, asteroids, meteors

I have just watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PENT_hnyO-o) made by discovery channel, and you can hear the narrator at 0:51 saying that : "even though it is moving at 720 THOUSANDS kilometers per hour..."

I stopped once I heard this, because I never thought an asteroid would ever travel that fast. So, is it a mistake since in the beginning of the video someone said "an object moving 20 kilometers a second.." or it could be correct ?

Also, if it is a mistake, then would a 20 km/s asteroid of that size cause the damage mentioned in the video ?

Comment: Fast compared to what?

Comment: Did you read what I just posted above ?

Comment: You can travel at any speed lower than $c$. I'm travelling  at 200000 m/s wrt. an arbitrary frame.

Comment: the question is about asteroid impact with earth, so it is wrt earth.

Comment: If you do the arithmetic, 720,000 km/hr= 200km/sec... Earth travels around the Sun at about about 30km/s. Solar escape velocity is around 600km/s at its surface, but only about 42km/s at Earth orbit, so a 20km/s delta-V with respect to Earth would not be exceptional for an object gravitationally bound to the Sun (such as a comet or asteroid), but a 200km/s delta-V would. Seems like the narrated value is a mistake, unless the origin of the asteroid is extrasolar, in which case its delta-V could be just about anything.

Comment: @AnthonyX, thank you. But one last thing, is the amount of damage mentioned in the video seems correct for an asteroid with velocity of 20km/s ?

Comment: http://www.spaceweather.com/ <BR> Two-thirds down. Daily fireballs are classified by speed, 12 - 72 km/sec in Earth's frame. You cans search backwards. Very interesting for meteor showers.

Comment: I don't claim to speak for anybody else (i.e. moderator hat very much off), but I *never* follow a link to watch a video to find out what someone is asking. It just doesn't happen; you are asking me to put time into your question before I know if I am interested in it. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/should-we-allow-embedding-videos-in-questions-or-answers and http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4918/how-to-deal-with-questions-based-on-videos for how others feel about that.

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim - I don't know. I found this which might provide some insight: http://impact.ese.ic.ac.uk/ImpactEffects/

Comment: @AnthonyX You should turn your comments into answers :)